# How to skip lines in Pycharm debug mode with Python?

Tags: python, pycharm

Let's say I put a breakpoint in the first line.
I see no option to simply skip the 2nd line and jump straight to the print statement.
Is there any hidden option? If not, what is the most non-intrusive way?
Commenting out the lines I don't wanna run is not elegant.

```
a = 3
a = 4
print(a)
```

Comment: debuger runs all code so you have to remove this line or comment it.

Comment: Why would you want to skip lines? If you want to know what it did at that point, right-click and open "evaluate expression" and paste the line you're interested in.

Comment: insert a condition before 2nd line in order to skip it through conditional logic.

Comment: as I said `debuger` runs all code - like in normal program.

Comment: @furas weirdly enough Gigioz' answer is working, it actually skips lines, feel free to also try it out

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do `right click` on the third statement and `Jump to Cursor`.
This is a manual action though... I don't think there is a mode to only run breakpointed lines...